# Android gradle+CMake - how to set number of build workers

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-ndk, cmake

I have an Android project (Android Studio 2.2) with tons of native c++ code (compiled with cmake invoked from gradles externalNativeBuild). By default cmake build started from gradle compiles native code with maximum number of workers (== CPU cores count), but it makes my machine unusable for 20 minutes. Therefore I want to specify manually how many cores should be used, what I did with -j switch in ndk-build. Is there possible to pass this information to build system from gradle?

There is documentation that tells how to pass arguments to first cmake call which generates ninja build scripts, but there is no documentation which tells how to pass arguments to cmake --build (ninja).

Is it possible to override number of workers from gradle for native cmake build?

Answer (score 0):

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL.html says that if `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL` environment is set, its value will be used as default amount of concurrent processes for `cmake --build` call.

This variable is available since CMake 3.12.

Comment: This has to be set in cmake command line args in gradle like externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments 
                        "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=4",?